# Alternative distribution of likelihood ratio test statistic

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, parameter-estimation

I am wondering if there is an existing theorem for the distribution of a likelihood ratio test statistic under the alternative.  By Wilks theorem, we know the distribution under the null.  However, under the alternative, I presume it is noncentral chisquare, but I can't seem to find anything on what the noncentrality parameter is.

I am specifically interested in the setting of Cox PH regression, where the density and hypotheses are as follows:

$$h(t) = h_0(t)exp(\beta X)$$

$$H_0: \beta = 0$$
$$H_1: \beta \neq 0$$

Using the partial likelihood of the Cox model, we can calculate the following likelihood ratio test statistic:

$$\lambda_LR = -2[l(\theta_0)-l(\hat{\theta})]$$

Any help would be much appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Noncentrality parameter depends on situation and on the specific alternative. What is parent population of data, test statistic, $H_0,$ and specific alternative value?

Comment: A similar question remains open on cross-validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/514380/non-centrality-of-likelihood-ratio-test-statistic-chi2-under-alternate-hypothesi Will be happy to know the answer.

Comment: @BruceET thank you for your comment.  I have updated the question to reflect this additional information.  Looking forward to hearing your thoughts!